# SwiftUI custom accentColor not working on physical device(iOS 13) but works everywhere else(iOS 14.0+)

Tags: swift, image, colors, swiftui, assets

In my SwiftUI `View` I've an `Image` that I've loaded from assets. I've set the `foregroundColor` to `accentColor`, which I've also set in asset as my custom `AccentColor` which is to be used throughout the app.

Asset:

[image: asset]

ContentView body:

```
var body: some View {
    Image("MyImageName")
        .resizable()
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
        .frame(width: 32, height: 32, alignment: .center)
}
```

The preview and the simulator show the image in the right `foregroundColor`. But, while running on a physical device the `foregroundColor` somehow remain the default blue `accentColor` of the phone.

Preview:

[image]

Simulator:

[image]

Real Device:

[image]

Why does this happen? And how do I make sure the `AssentColor` work across devices no matter the iOS version without modifying any settings on the iPhone? Debug details: The device iOS version is iOS 13.5.1 and Xcode 12.0.1.

Comment: .accentColor is already defined in the system. How and where, exactly, did you attempt to redefine it? Lastly, why did you not just set your foregroundColor directly to your asset color?

Comment: Check the version of Xcode and iOS that I've specified in the OP. You'll find `.accentColor` doesn't work as expected on a real device as it does on a simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, while testing further I found that even though `accentColor` is available from `iOS 13.0`, customizing `accentColor` is only available from `iOS 14.0`. So I created an extension to use the `accentColor` from asset manually in `iOS 13` and work normally in `iOS 14.0` and above.

```
extension Color {

    static var accent: Color {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            return accentColor
        } else {
            return Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.5, green: 0.5, blue: 0.5, alpha: 1))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to leave a reminder here that the global app tint color can be broken by accessing properties of the application (including selection color, tint colors, etc) or constructing some views before the application creates the first UIWindow.

If tint color is broken everywhere (including in the simulator) make sure you're not trying to construct or access UIKit components before your first window, including third party SDKs. In my app, a third-party crash logging SDK was breaking the accent color.

Answer (score 2):

`Color.accentColor` works fine, even changing it on a `View` with `.accentColor(newColor)` works on iOS 13.

The only problem is that iOS 13 doesn't set `Color.accentColor` to the color in the assets specified by `ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_GLOBAL_ACCENT_COLOR_NAME`.

What worked for me was to do that step manually by simply setting the `window.tintColor` to that color:

```swift
if #available(iOS 14, *) {} else {
  window.tintColor = UIColor(named: "AccentColor")
}
```